# Java Swing, create a panel over a window by its hwnd handler

Tags: java, windows, swing, java-native-interface, hwnd

I'm writing a java app and at some point I create a window using Windows API through JNI.

How can I create a jpanel over a part of that window so I can add gui to it in the java side?

If that's not possible, then can I create a window in java and set it's parent to the first 
window to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Why do you need to create a native window using JNI?  What's wrong with `JWindow`, `JDialog` or `JFrame`?

Comment: It's a vst plugin window, for what I have a c++ library that creates the synth's window.

Comment: Swing GUI's are built to be as OS-agnostic as possible, making your request very difficult if not impossible to achieve.